# How to float an image in Gutenberg

Tags: theme-development, images, css, block-editor

I am trying to make my first post in Gutenberg and I've discovered that aligning the image right around the blocks works in the editor but when I preview it is not floating right.

Previously I had css for img.alignright now the alignright class is applied to a figure tag, so I updated my style.css and it still doesn't work. I even inserted custom html as follows:

```
<img class="alignright" src="http://blah.com/image.jpg" />
```

And that didn't work though when I view source in the preview it should be just like before Gutenberg. Is there some theme support thing I need to add? I took screen shots as I searched too and others have had issues similar but I followed their advice and it didn't help. I also discovered you can't insert an image from a relative URL in Gutenberg. I could not link directly to my preview so I had to [publish a post](http://blog.muschamp.ca/2019/01/26/top-10-china-posts/) in a theme that clearly isn't ready for Gutenberg, but obviously my 20+ years of coding HTML is insufficient to solving this problem as clearly I have been doing other things lately than coding.
[image: Image in Gutenberg]

[image: Image previewed in Safari]

[image: CSS rules for the image as custom HTML block]

Comment: what is the site address?

Comment: blog.muschamp.ca but this is my first Gutenberg post and it is unpublished so I couldn't link directly to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two methods, which can be used:

#### Method 1

Add `Classic` block, and insert, as the only element, a right aligned image, into that block. Add other blocks, after the `Classic` block.

#### Method 2

Add `Image` block, and add `alignright` class, in Advanced setting of this block. Follow that `Image` block by other blocks.

> I also discovered you can't insert an image from a relative URL in
>   Gutenberg.

Media Library always provides full URL of the image. After the image is inserted, switch from Visual Editor to Code Editor, and edit `src` attribute of `img` element to use a relative URL.

Comment: I can't believe the braintrust at WordPress made it this hard to insert an image. Hopefully one of these will work, I'm still disappointed my HTML block didn't work. I tried adding another class and CSS rules using advanced I made another one called "floatRight". Obviously I couldn't like to a preview of an unpublished post...

Comment: Method 1 did not work. It looks exactly like before. I think my custom HTML solution was the same. I even switched browsers to Chrome to see if this was a Safari thing, I can add another picture, but it has to be something in my theme or style.css

Comment: Method 2 also did not work. I still think my custom HTML block should have worked it has to be a CSS inheritance issue, should the image be display:block?

Comment: I think it might have something to do with trying to float around a heading which of course I used to be able to do in all my old posts. I really am not a happy chappy having spent hours trying to float a single image right.

Comment: After following method 2 I can not delete the image. I also don't think Chrome is reloading my CSS when I hit refresh, did I mention I had the entire post written and just need to add the images, this has cost me hours of time, this is not an improvement to WordPress.

Comment: With both methods, the block ( either Classic or Image ) has to be inserted just BEFORE the first of blocks, the image is supposed to float around. The sequence is important.

Comment: I don't see why I can't float around an H2 tag. I could float around an H2 tag back in the 90s, I want the tall skinny image to float right of all paragraphs and subheadings like I've done hundreds of times before, here without any H2s http://blog.muschamp.ca/2017/12/21/shanghai-tour-guide/ And I did put the image before the heading block that seems to be the problem, it can float around a paragraph but not a heading.

Comment: It should float around a heading block, and following paragraps, as well. I've tested it with various themes on many sites, and it works without any problems.

Comment: I used to be able to do it too as seen here: http://blog.muschamp.ca/2010/11/28/spammers-scammers-and-other-internet-assholes/ but now I can not as seen in my latest blog post. This really has been hours of effort to float an image, something I've been doing for well over a decade.

Comment: Could you edit your question, and paste code, copied from Code Editor, for `Image` block, followed by `Heading` block, and `Paragraph` block? Without seeing this code I cannot determine the cause of your problem.

Comment: I think I added a third screenshot above with the information you want but if not, I also published the post so you can view source at your leisure. Thank you for all your assistance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88837/discussion-between-frank-p-walentynowicz-and-muskie).

Comment: The fix was display: inline; on that H2 rule but I don't know where it got display: block. Now I have to see if it messes up anything else. I used to not use H1 and H2 so much, but for SEO purposes I am using them more. I used to use mostly H3 and H4...

Comment: @Muskie I am having the exact same problem you were originally having. It looks fine in the editor, but not on the live site. I've tried the various things discussed in this thread, but nothing works. Did you ever figure it out? (I'm not using an H2, I'm just trying to get a paragraph to wrap around the alignright image). This is an internal blog, so I have no link.

Comment: Yes someone on here helped me. My WordPress theme is old from 2005 I just keep updating it and someday I may start over may using _s as a base, but use Chrome debug this, it is definitely better for CSS debugging than Safari. Look at the inheritance. My issue was I had set just H2 somewhere to not display inline as I was using it on my archives as the title, but switched to using it in posts. Previously I had used H1 for main title, H2 for post titles in archives and H3 to avoid issues for subtitles. There were no H2 or H1 tags in any posts, but for SEO purposes I started using H2. Good Luck!